# XPComment and XPKeywords does not appear when writing exif metadata

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, exif

XPComment and XPKeywords does not appear when writing exif metadata.

```py
from PIL import Image
filepath = "yourFilepath.jpg"
image = Image.open(filepath)

XPComment = 0x9C9C
XPKeywords = 0x9C9E
exifdata = image.getexif()
exifdata[XPComment] = "new comment"
exifdata[XPKeywords] = "new keyword;"

image.save(filepath, exif=exifdata)
# ???? where's my exif data yo?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be encoded in utf-16 format. The necessary encoding may vary depending on your computer.

```py
from PIL import Image
filepath = "yourFilepath.jpg"
image = Image.open(filepath)

XPComment = 0x9C9C
XPKeywords = 0x9C9E
exifdata = image.getexif()
exifdata[XPComment] = "new comment".encode("utf16")
exifdata[XPKeywords] = "new keyword;".encode("utf16")

image.save(filepath, exif=exifdata)
# it appears! :D
```